# How to launch a marketplace image (colab) on a Spot instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Let's say there's a marketplace image, e.g. [Colab](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/colab-marketplace-image-public/colab).
I want to launch it on a GCE spot instance. When I use the Deployment Manager, there is no option to choose the spot provisioning model.
Neither documentation nor googling helps. Is there a way to launch a marketplace image on a spot instance?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to extract the cloud init configuration and properties from an instance created by the marketplace and deployment manager. I posted it [on gist](https://gist.github.com/alexandrnikitin/4acabec89f0f709af2e82b7da5c6def7). Let me know if you know a better solution.

Here's the gcloud command to launch a spot instance with Colab image and cloud init configuration. The setup happens in `cloud_init.conf`, see the gist above.

```
gcloud beta compute instances create colab-1-vm \
--machine-type=e2-highmem-4 \
--provisioning-model=SPOT \
--boot-disk-size=200GB \
--boot-disk-type=pd-balanced \
--instance-termination-action=DELETE \
--image=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/colab-marketplace-image-public/global/images/colab-mp-20220110 \
--network=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<INSERT_PROJECT_ID>/global/networks/default \
--subnet=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<INSERT_PROJECT_ID>/regions/<INSERT_REGION>/subnetworks/default \
--no-restart-on-failure \
--metadata-from-file=user-data=cloud_init.conf \
--service-account=<INSERT_ACCOUNT>@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud.useraccounts.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Alexandrs contribution, I added support for a GPU in [this forked gist](https://gist.github.com/Victordmz/2d0ad50bad8be423eac7a612e5a7b291).

*Edit 2023*: I updated the gist to the most recent Google Colab image (with the newest Python version).

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble getting the other approaches working ([this one](https://serverfault.com/a/1090444/978345) or [this one](https://serverfault.com/a/1090449/978345)). However, after some experimentation I found another approach that works for me:

1. Use the deployment manager with the marketplace Colab image.
2. Go to "VM instances" in Compute Engine, and stop the instance. Click on the instance name, and create a machine image (using the "create machine image" button).
3. After the machine image is created, click on the "create instance" button, and select "New VM instance from machine image" on the left. Now you can configure the instance as desired, including Spot provisioning. Finally, click on the "equivalent command line" button, and run that command through the gcloud tool. Directly clicking on the "create" button didn't work for me (due to some contradicting parameters), but using the gcloud command seems to fix that issue.
4. You should now be able to connect to the instance through Colab, selecting "connect to a custom GCE VM".

Answer (score 0):

Create Spot VMs using the gcloud tool or the Compute Engine API. Spot VMs are any VMs that are configured to use the spot provisioning model: --provisioning-model=SPOT in the gcloud tool or "provisioningModel": "SPOT" in the Compute Engine API.

Please refer to the documents about how to [Create Spot VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-use-spot#create) on GCP.

After connecting to the server using,

```
$ gcloud compute ssh --zone us-central1-a 'instance-name' -- -L 8888:localhost:8888
```

Install and set up the necessary libraries to connect to a Colab frontend by using the following command:

```
$ pip install jupyter_http_over_ws jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws jupyter notebook  
--NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0 --no-browser
```

To connect to a Colab frontend, we get an URL as an output of the above command.

When you click the URL’s in the terminal it will redirect to the Jupyter home page successfully without any problems.

Refer [Colab+GCP Compute](https://medium.com/@senthilnathangautham/colab-gcp-compute-how-to-link-them-together-98747e8d940e) — how to link them together for more information.